# Run mapreduce program for list of words inputs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have ***words.txt***, a file which contain a large set of unique words as below

```
book
apple
football
camera
playing
mac
Google
samsung
..
```

And I have designed a map reduce program to log and count how many words appeared with word 'Google' in each line in a large corpus.txt file.

For example, if we assume the below corpus:

```
.......
........
Google receives more than 345 million
Google handled 345 million
........
.......
```

The output of the program is:

```
[Google,receives]     1
[Google,more]         1
[Google,than]         1
[Google,million]      2
[Google,345]          2
[Google,handled]      1
```

The program is working fine for a single word. But the question is how to run the program for the whole list of words in words.txt file?

I mean, should I run a mapreduce job for each word in the list, or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. We cannot help you if you don't provide more information: What is the code that you used? What is your expected output?

Comment: 'large set of words' - how large? will the corpus fit in memory?